# Change Android Dialog background to different color

Tags: android, dialog

I have a Dialog that I display in my application, but I want to be able to change the semi-transparent black background to be 100% transparent. Like below, the part that grays out the activity behind the dialog, I'd like that to be transparent so that I can see the underlying activity as it, instead of being darkened. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs

Comment: Try it here: [Dialog with transparent background in Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10795234/2423066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my desired result by creating the Dialog and passing a style to its constructor like so...

```
 Dialog ad = new Dialog(context, R.style.SpinnerDialogDropdown);


<style name="SpinnerDialogDropdown">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    **<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>**
</style>
```