# Why is My Android Alert dialog BLACK?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

Can you help my figure out why is my alert dialog BLACK?!

*Recently i changed my app theme to support material design, but my alert dialog got black!*

Here is my create dialog Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.setTitle("sample");
    alertDialog.setItems(new String[] { "a", "b" }, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
```

and its my main style and dialog style

```
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AppDialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppDialog</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppDialog</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>
</style>
```

Comment: see the excepted ans, might be you can resolve your issue with this approach > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set theme for AlertDialog, for using theme, change code to:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(TestActivity.this, R.style.AppDialog);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
```

Answer (score 2):

you must use a light theme with your alertdialog builder such as the THEME_HOLO_LIGHT.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Comment: Thank you, for your comment, it is true. however, i think it is simple and explains itself.

Comment: But this is deprecated?