# Android: Default theme on ContextMenu?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-theme

I was wondering if there's any way to assign the default android theme on a context menu.
I have a custom theme applied to my whole application in the android manifest,and I don't want to apply it individually to each activity.

I've been able to achieve this in a `Toast` with `getApplicationContext()`. This way my custom theme doesn't override the `Toast` default theme. Example:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_agenda, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Is there any way to do something similar on a `ContextMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to change the alertDialogStyle in your custom theme.  Hope this could meet your requirement.

Comment: As far as I've read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118601/how-can-i-change-the-background-of-android-alert-dialogs) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524051/button-style-in-alertdialogs) this isn't possible without creating my own custom `Dialog`. Is there any way of just calling the default theme and not having to create a new `Dialog` class?