# Color of highlight/pressed state of dialog button after custom theming?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, android-theme

I used [this](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate a custom theme for my application (basically just a nice green instead of the default blue)

I have a `CheckBox` in my app, and it has the green hue applied. I also have textviews, and the underlines are colored correctly.

But if I use

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to build a confirm dialog, the `No` and `Yes` buttons critically have the default holo blue - it's really jarring in that everything else in the app is consistently themed.

How can I get to that color and change it? I'd really love to not have to define an entire custom dialog view just to solve this single color problem.

Comment: Haven't tried `holo-colors.com/` but you could check their result against [this description](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13762349/1856738), maybe it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an alert with a custom theme you have to use another constructor:

[`AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int theme)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

Something like this should be enough:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.your_theme);
```

I would also recommend to use a custom version of [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and that way you can have all your formatted dialogs in one place. And, on top of that, DialogFragment is automatically restored on rotation ;)