# Rate my app dialog when the user want to exit my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rate

I want to change the dialog of exit app with twi choices choice 1 = "rate" and choice 2 = "exit"  now i can only show exit or stay dialog but i want to convert it to what i described here is the code :

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setNeutralButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   PicSelect.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();
}
```

and this the class code `

public class PicSelect extends SherlockActivity {

```
private GridView photoGrid;
private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
private Itemadapter imageAdapter;
private AdView mAdView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picselct);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#c5d951")));
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewad);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
    mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);
    photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

    Model.LoadModel();
    String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
    for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++){
        ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
    }

    imageAdapter=new Itemadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.photo_item,ids,"CATIMAGE");
    photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
            photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                        final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                        if (numColumns > 0) {
                            final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                            imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                            imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            photoGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("FolderName", Model.GetbyId(position+1).FolderName);

                    String FolderName=Model.GetbyId(position+1).FolderName;
                    String CategoryName=Model.GetbyId(position+1).Name;
                    Intent i=new Intent(PicSelect.this,PicItem.class);
                    i.putExtra("Folder", FolderName);
                    i.putExtra("Category", CategoryName);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setNeutralButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   PicSelect.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{       

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
    {

    case R.id.rateapp:

        final String appName = getPackageName();//your application package name i.e play store application url
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                            + appName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                            + appName)));
        }
        return true;

    case R.id.moreapp:

        startActivity(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_more_apps))));

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }

}
```

}
`

finaly if anyone know how to style the text thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.setNegativeButton("Rate App", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=[your package name]"));
                   startActivity(i);
               }
           })
```

This will give you a negative option that says Rate App that when clicked opens the market to your app.

Comment: Works perfect thank you the you have any idea how to style the text ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524051/button-style-in-alertdialogs

Answer (score 0):

Improve your app with this snippet in onBackPressed():

```
 if(isTaskRoot()) {
            if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 2000) {
                toast = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.hinweisBeendeApp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else {
                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                }
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```